# VisualStudio 2013+.json file. How to use utf8 coding?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I'm using a template for a hub app for Windows Phone 8.1 from VisualStudio and when I change value in
.json file section, from a default  to "żółw" the debuger tell me:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> WinRT information: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the
>   target multi-byte code page.

And bring me to following method:

```
  private async void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
        {

            var sampleDataGroups = await SampleDataSource.GetGroupsAsync();
            this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"] = sampleDataGroups;
        }
```

How can I use utf-8 char in .json file to get my app work propetly?

Comment: Have a look at [this article](http://drew5.net/2014/01/10/winrt-information-no-mapping-for-the-unicode-character-exists-in-the-target-multi-byte-code-page/)

Comment: i have allready utf-8 :/

Answer (score 0):

CTRL + Q to go to the quick launch ,then input :document, and get into the "environment -->document". then ensure the "save document as Unicode when data cannot be saved in codepage" was checked. clik Ok .

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the json file in an external editor i.e Notepad++ with the letters and the expressions you need in your language . Then save this file in UTF8 from within the external editor. VS2013 update 5 identified and used correctly the Greek letters I have used. If you edit now the json file from within VS the formatting will be kept ( no issues in my case).
Hope I have offered some help!

Answer (score 0):

Most json encoders encode non-ascii characters to their unicode value, like this:

```
$array = ['somekey' => 'żółw'];
echo json_encode($array);
```

results in:

```
{"somekey":"\u017c\u00f3\u0142w"}
```